# error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'StudentDbContext' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-code

So I'm working in vs code not the IDE and when I build the project I get this error:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'StudentDbContext' could not be found

I'm using .NET 8 and the latest version of dotnet ef.

Here is my Program.cs file where the error is:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; 

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();


builder.Services.AddDbContext<StudentDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

It's at the top of the file where I'm configuring my database connection.

The other similar question either did not apply or where out of date.

I've tried updating and reinstall everything but I'm still getting the same output

Comment: To eliminate the obvious first, does the project contain a class called StudentDBContext?

Comment: And where is `StudentDbContext` defined?  In what namespace is it defined?  Are you `using` that namespace at the top of this file?

Comment: Yes, it does and it's located in the Data folder which is at the root of the project so same place Program.cs is located

Comment: In the file where `StudentDbContext` is defined, is there a `namespace` specified?  What happens when you add a `using` directive for that `namespace` to this file?

Comment: Highly likely that you need to add something like: `using YourProjectName.Data` (the namespace where the context class is located) to the top of the program file.

Comment: Yes, I have a namespace in the context file. Where should I put the using directive for context in the Program.cs file?

Comment: I see I'll add that and see what happens. Thank you

Comment: So can this question be closed now?

Comment: Sure why not. My bad for not asking a perfect question on SO anyway